# Null value after json deserialization on windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone

I am using the Json.DeserializeObject method in windows phone, inorder to deserialize json, the problem I am having is one of the variable names, in the json has a space and I just can't get it to deserialize. it returns a null the whole time, and if I view the raw json it does contain a value

part of raw json:

```
 \"Service Provider\":Test\"
```

When I try to generate a class for the json into which it needs to be deserialized, the Service Provider section tells me "Invalid Name" and that obviously doesn't work in C# as a variable name, but I believe the variable name can be anything:

```
  public string __invalid_name__Service Provider { get; set; }
```

current code:

```
  public string Service_Provider { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you using the Json.Net library, or is it WP8 built-in json classes?

Comment: Your Json is malformed. It's missing a beginning quote on the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), Just decorate your property with "JsonProperty" Attribute

```
string json = @"{""Service Provider"":""Test""}";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TempObject>(json);


public class TempObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Service Provider")]
    public string ServiceProvider;
}
```